# Boto3 AWS creating user Try catch not allowing the for loop to conrtinue

Tags: python, boto3

I have this python script that will go through all my accounts and create a user in each but I get an error when the user already exists 'botocore.errorfactory.EntityAlreadyExistsException:' or it will only create the user in the account until it hits and error the the for loop ends and never creates the user in the exiting accounts in the array.  I have tried the botocore exceptions and moving the exception pass to other lines in the code when I do that I get no output.  Also this creates a second set of keys. I am a bit of a newbie with Python...

```
import boto3
import pprint
import sys
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError, ParamValidationError
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
username='musicman'
Password = 'Welcome'
accounts = ["account1", "account2", "account3", "account4", "account5", "account6"]
try:
for account in accounts:
    boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name=account)
    #brooksprod = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='account1')
    iam = boto3.client('iam')

    # create a user
    iam.create_user( UserName=username)
except Exception:
       pass
response = iam.add_user_to_group(
    GroupName='Admin',
    UserName=username
)
response = iam.create_login_profile(
    UserName= username,
    Password= Password,
    PasswordResetRequired=True
)    
    #pp.pprint(response)
response = iam.get_user(UserName = username)
pp.pprint(response)

response = iam.create_access_key(
    UserName=username
)
#print(response.get('AccessKey','SecretAccessKey'))
pp.pprint(response)
```

Comment: Put your try inside the for loop. You want to "try" each element you're looping over right? As it stands now, you are trying to do the for loop once. As soon as it hits an exception, the for loop is exited.

Answer (score 1):

Do the `try/except` inside the for loop:

```
for account in accounts:
  try:
    boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name=account)
    #brooksprod = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='account1')
    iam = boto3.client('iam')

    # create a user
    iam.create_user( UserName=username)
  except Exception:
    pass
```